# change the function wp_list_pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to do a sitemap for my website, I used in `wp_list_pages`
but the function made me only `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

I want to define title with `h2` tag and sub pages in `h3` tag
how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need it? I guess you can customize look of `<ul>`/`<li>` tags using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you might give these a try:

## 1 take a look at your CSS and modify the class "pagenav".

or, and it might be better,

## 2 create a filter, which modifies your layout, and hook it into "wp_list_pages"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read this:

> By default, wp_list_pages() generates
>   a nested, unordered list of WordPress
>   Pages created with the Write > Page
>   admin panel. You can remove the
>   outermost item (li.pagenav) and list
>   (ul) by setting the title_li parameter
>   to an empty string.

Found it on: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages  under the "Markup and styling of page items" section.

I hope it helps.